# rails belongs_to foreign key is null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, foreign-keys, associations, belongs-to

i have the following models

```
class User    
has_many :projects, :through => :bids
has_many :bids, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Project
attr_accessible :name, :user_id

has_many :users, :through => :bids
has_many :bids, :dependent => :destroy

belongs_to :projectmanager, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "user_id"

end

class Bid
attr_accessible :project_id, user_id
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :project
end
```

As you can see, my **Project** class has both *has_many* and *belongs_to* to the same model (**User**)

In **Project** controller **new** I have

```
def new
@project = Project.new
@project.gencontr = current_user
```

where **current_user** is Devise current logged in user.

When I save the project, the column **user_id** in the **Projects** table is always null. Can you show me where do I go wrong on this one...Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on create action

```
def create
  @project = Project.new(prams[:project])
  @project.projectmanager = current_user
  .......
end
```

Comment: another cleaner implementation would be ```current_user.projects.create(params[:project])```